# Can one associate a matrix with a bilinear map?

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider a bilinear map $A : \mathcal{U} \oplus \mathcal{V} \to \mathcal{W}$ defined by $A({\bf u},{\bf v}) = {\bf u} - {\bf v}$, where $\mathcal{U}, \mathcal{V} \subset \mathcal{W}$.

Is there anyway to associate a matrix to this map like we do for bilinear forms or ordinary linear maps from one vector space to another?

Thanks.

Comment: It *is* an ordinary linear map from one vector space to another.

Comment: Well it's a direct sum so I would assume that this implies two vector spaces.

Comment: Direct sum creates one vector space from two.

Comment: Okay then, what is the matrix associated with this linear map?

Comment: You need to choose bases to make a matrix, after which you proceed as usual. In any case, my input to this question ends here because I'm going to sleep.